# Show members of group outside /group/members/ page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm having a hard time showing a simple list of members of a group on the home of a group. The code works on the /group/members/ page. But it doesn't work on the home of a group.

The documentation says (https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/loops-reference/the-group-members-loop-bp_group_has_members/):

**group_id required**
The ID of the group to fetch members for. Required when either: outside of the normal BuddyPress groups URL (/group/i-love-bp/members/) or not nested within a bp_has_groups() loop.

So that is exactly what I did, but still no luck. Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'group_id' => bp_get_group_id()
    );

    if ( bp_group_has_members( $args ) ) : ?>

        <ul id="member-list" class="item-list">
            <?php while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); ?>

                <li>
                    <span class="avatar">
                        <a href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">
                            <?php bp_group_member_avatar_thumb(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="name">
                        <a href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">
                            <h4><?php bp_group_member_name(); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="actions">
                        <a class="button small" href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">
                            <?php esc_html_e('View profile', 'mvp'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </span>

                </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

    <?php else: ?>

        <div id="message" class="info">
            <p><?php _e( 'No members were found.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, was breaking my head about this one for the past days. But found the solution, of course the answer was right there. I forgot to exclude admins and mods in the loop. Don't understand why they would be excluded in the first place.

There is the complete code, including to get xProfile fields for anyone that is interested:

````
<?php
    $args = array(
        'group_id' => bp_get_group_id(),
        'exclude_admins_mods' => false
    );

    if ( bp_group_has_members( $args ) ) : ?>
        <ul id="member-list" class="item-list">
            <?php while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); ?>

                <?php $user_id = bp_get_group_member_id(); ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="avatar">
                        <a href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">
                            <?php bp_group_member_avatar_thumb(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="name">
                        <a href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">
                            <h4><?php bp_group_member_name(); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="platforms">
                        <?php $user_psn_handle = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=PSN handle&user_id='.$user_id); ?>
                        <?php if($user_psn_handle): ?>
                            <i class="icon saturated standalone platform psn"></i>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php $user_xbox_handle = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=XBOX handle&user_id='.$user_id); ?>
                        <?php if($user_xbox_handle): ?>
                            <i class="icon saturated standalone platform xbox"></i>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </span>
                    <span class="actions">
                        <a class="button small" href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">
                            <?php esc_html_e('View profile', 'mvp'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </span>

                </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

    <?php else: ?>

        <div id="message" class="info">
            <p><?php _e( 'No members were found.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    ```
````